# determine which element I am in among siblings using jquery

Tags: jquery

the question is fairly obvious but I don't know how to solve it

```
<div id="" class="sublistB cf">
    <div class="topTab" title="click to select all options in this column"><span class="gray">(All)</span></div>
    <div class="topTab" title="click to select all options in this column"><span class="gray">(All)</span></div>
</div>
```

How do I determine which element "I" am among siblings on click? without using an id or special value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.topTab').click(function(){
       //var a value for the position of the element clicked within .sublistB
       //in this case either 0 or 1
    }
```

Comment: `$(this)` and/or `.index()`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/ for @j08691

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `click` function, you just need to use `$(this)` which will give you your current item.

```
$('.topTab').click(function(){
   $(this).doWhatever(); // $(this) is the currently clicked item
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use target attribute of event like below:

While calling function pass event parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.topTab').click(function(event){
  console.log(event.target);
 });
});
```

wrap event.target with $ so that you can use all the jquery functions.
like

```
$(event.target).css("color","red")
```

will change the clicked div text color to red.

Example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wokihayiwonu/1/edit)

Comment: this did not relate in any way to the question I was asking.  I asked "how do I determine $(this)'s relationship numerically to other siblings inside a parent.

Comment: You cant event understood what you've asked. You asked 'How do I determine which element "I" am among siblings on click? without using an id or special value.' In my example whenever you click on any div, you are able to identify the div you've clicked (the corresponding div's color will change to red) that means you're determining the div

Comment: First ask question correctly. In your question You've asked to determine which element you've clicked on but now you are asking "relationship with other elements ..."

Comment: At first Gangadhar I thought you had a point, but in the comment I have        //var a value for the position of the element clicked within .sublistB
       //in this case either 0 or 1 - which is very clear

Comment: what do you mean by "//var a value for the position of the element clicked within .sublistB
       //in this case either 0 or 1". How could one understand that?

Comment: The first person to respond did! See their answer.  Anyway, according to SO if you'll edit your post slightly I can undo the -1, sorry about that.

Comment: @SamuelFullman I'm least bother about -1, still I didn't get what you asked. Anyway, $(this) and $(event.target) is also same in my opinion, moreover this is context parameter so if you trigger any events that might cause 'this' to loose its scope. Thanks for your suggestion